# Python zip file transfer throws error while unziping

Tags: python, zip, fileserver

I am trying to send a zip file from a client to a server machine. The client zips the content properly, but the server is unable to receive the content and unzip it.

Server Code:

```
import socket
import sys
import os
import zipfile

HOST = ""
PORT = 9999

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(5)
target = "C:\\first example\\Python_exapmles\\Recieved_files"
output = os.path.join(target, "result.zip")

print("Listening ...")
# output="result.zip"
foo = zipfile.ZipFile(output, 'w')
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("[+] Client connected: ", addr)
    # get file name to download
    foo = open(output, "wb")
    while True:
        # get file bytes
        data = conn.recv(4096)
        print(data)
        if not data:
            break
        # write bytes on file
        foo.write(data)

    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(r'C:\\first example\\Python_exapmles\\Recieved_files\\result.zip')
    zip.extractall(r'C:\\first example\\Python_exapmles\\after_extract')
    foo.close()
    print("[+] Download complete!")
    # close connection
    conn.close()
    print("[-] Client disconnected")

    sys.exit(0)
```

Client code:

```
import socket
import sys
import sys
import os
import zipfile

host= '192.168.1.205'
port=9999

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host,port))

print("[+] connected with server")

source="C:\\New folder\\zipfoldername"
target='C:\\New folder'
output=os.path.join(target, "01-lam-nat-conv.zip")
print (output)
foo = zipfile.ZipFile(output, 'w')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
    path=root.replace(source, "01-lam-nat-conv")
    #prist path
    for f in files:
        foo.write(os.path.join(root, f), path + "//" + f)  # zipfile.ZIP_STORED)



f_send=output
#open file

with open(f_send,"rb") as f:
    data=f.read()
    s.sendall(data)

    s.close()
    sys.exit(0)
```

The output after running the client will exit with a "exit code 0" and the zip is properly done but in the server I get the following error.

> line 1108, in **init**  & line 1175, in _RealGetContents zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Comment: You're writing to ``result123.zip`` but you're trying to extract ``result.zip``.

Comment: sorry about that mike. I have same name at both the places but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

In the Server Code you are assigning the value to `foo` variable two times
`foo = zipfile.ZipFile(output, 'w')` and `foo = open(output, "wb")`

`foo` does not remains the *Zipfile* anymore after the execution of the latter line
Removing the latter line should fix your code

Comment: thanks pulkit. I did change it other variable and it worked fine..                               regards sagar\